# Reactjs - get value from array

Tags: reactjs

I have a list of images, I want to get the name of the image that is in the zero position of the matrix.

[image]

As you can see in the image, the name is inside File. But when I try `items[0].file` or `items[0]['file']` the error `TypeError returns: Cannot read property 'file' of undefined`

My code:

```
export function Multiple() {

    const handleChange = files => {
      files.map(file => {
        setItems(item => [
          ...item,
          {
            file,
            onRemove: handleOnRemove,
            onClick: handleOnClick
          }
        ]);
      });
    };
  
    const handleOnRemove = file => {
      setItems(item => [...item.filter(item => item.file.name !== file.name)]);
    };
  
    const handleOnClick = file => {
      getBase64(file)
      setNameImage(file.name)
      setIsOpen(true)
    };
  
    const [items, setItems] = React.useState([]);
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = React.useState(false);
    const [nameImage, setNameImage] = React.useState('');
    const [codeImage, setCodeImage] = React.useState('');
  
    function getBase64(file) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onload = function () {
        setCodeImage(reader.result)
      };
      reader.onerror = function (error) {
        console.log('Error: ', error);
      };
    }
  
    React.useEffect(() => {
      return console.log(items[0]['file'])
    }, [items]);
  
  
    return (
      <>
        <File
          name="image"
          label="Upload de imagens"
          onChange={handleChange}
          required={true}
          multiple={true}
        >
          {items.map((item, index) => (
            <File.Item {...item} key={index} />
          ))}
        </File>
  
        <Modal
          title={nameImage}
          onClose={() => setIsOpen(false)}
          show={isOpen}
        >
          <img src={codeImage} alt='Imagem' className='image' />
        </Modal>
      </>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Can we have your component code ?

Comment: I put the code in the body of the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you first initialize items, it is an empty array so trying to log items[0].file will give error. Add undefined check. Also do not return it from useEffect. Return in [useEffect](https://tr.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) is used for cleanup logic.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
 if(items[0] {
  console.log(items[0]['file'])
 }

}, [items]);
```

Comment: Just curious, how can you make this dynamic without the use of [0] ?

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic?

Comment: suppose if op wanted to use index opposed to using [0] hardcoded? how would you go about finding the index key

Comment: This check was added to avoid the initial empty state. If you want to check for any random index you can store the index in the state and check for items[state.myDynamicIndex]